# For loop with strings, arrays, and controls

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

I figured it out...

one last thing:

How do I write the code so that the one in "EFFICIENCY_STACKRANK_YTD(LblStckRnk1.Text)
" is able to change value with the i?

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    EFFICIENCY_STACKRANK_YTD(LblStckRnk1.Text)
    StackPCT(i) = "StackPCT" + (1).ToString
    myArray(i) = Controls.Find(StackPCT(i), False)
    myControl(i) = myArray(i)(0)
    myControl(i).Text = RESULT1
Next
```

Comment: can you give us a hint what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Joseph.Scott.Garza What are you using?  Winforms or ASP.net Webforms?

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm just trying to write less code using a for loop.

Comment: @Mike C, I'm using a windows form application.

Comment: Where are you assigning RESULT1

Comment: Joseph, then mission accomplished.  You have written code that utilizes a for loop.  However, if you have additional expectations on how this code should behave, you will need to clarify what you would like it to do.

Comment: That sql string is vulnerable to injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each loop iteration, you can dynamically find a control:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10    
    ' dynamically find a control using a fixed string plus a dynamic iteration counter.
    ' first iteration it will find LblStckRnk0
    ' second iteration it will find LblStckRnk1
    ' etc.
    ' beware of Controls that dont exist, or it will have a runtime error.
    EFFICIENCY_STACKRANK_YTD(DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("LblStckRnk" & i, True).FirstOrDefault(), TextBox).Text)    
    ' removed remaining code.    
Next
```

Comment: when I enter that code, I get an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: This starts at iteration #0, do you have a `LblStckRnk0` or do you start at 1 on your form?

Comment: I start with LblStckRnk1

Comment: The loop counter starts at 0 and goes to 10, performing 11 iterations. How many controls do you have exactly? (when I do find control, I now incremented the counter by 1)

Comment: I have LblStckRnk1 -  LblStckRnk10

Comment: OK, can you try the updated code. I needed to modify the outer `FOR LOOP` to do ten iterations instead of 11.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each lbl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Where(Function(l) l.Name Like "StackPCT#*")
    lbl.Text = RESULT1
Next lbl
```

---

**Update:**
That sql method has some *really* bad practices. Here's something better:

```
Private Function EFFICIENCY_STACKRANK_YTD(ByVal EMPLOYEE As String) As Integer

    Dim sql As String = _
        "SELECT CAST(SUM(TARGET_SECONDS) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(SUM(ROUTE_SECONDS) AS DECIMAL) RESULT1 " & _
        "FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WITH(NOLOCK) " & _ 
        "WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = @AreaObj AND EMPLOYEE_NAME= @Employee " & _
           " AND YEAR_TIME= @Year AND ACTIVE=1"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStr), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AreaObj", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = Integer.Parse(lblAreaOBJID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Employee", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = EMPLOYEE
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = Integer.Parse(cbYear.Text)

        cn.Open()
        Return DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Use it like this:

```
Dim RESULT1 As Integer = EFFICIENCY_STACKRANK_YTD(EMPLOYEE)
For Each lbl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Where(Function(l) l.Name Like "StackPCT#*")
    lbl.Text = RESULT1
Next lbl
```

Comment: I tried this and got "0" for all my "StackPCTXX" labels except for StackPCT10 which remained = to "StackPCT10"

Comment: @Joseph.Scott.Garza that's because you are not retrieving the RESULT1 value correctly. You were looking up the _column index_ in the sql results, and not the value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real reason to stash controls in an array.  Rather than copying a reference from `Controls()` (a form control collection??) just create a list of control names as a  `List(of String)` representing the controls names:

```
Private ctlName As New List(of String)

For i As Integer = 0 To 10 
    ctlName.Add("StackPCT" & i.ToString
Next i
```

To get a control ref:

```
ctl = Controls(ctlName(IndexOfControlYouWant))
ctl.Text = RESULT1
' or

Controls(ctlName(Index)).Text = RESULT1
```